# Using JQuery, how can I check when a popup has finished loading?

Tags: profile, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to hide some fields on a Profile based on user input by attaching JQuery events to the form elements.

So I have successfully attached a function to CRM.popup according to: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/ajax/ using the "crmPopupOpen" event but this is fired before the form is rendered (so no elements to attach to).

How do I know when the popup form has completed loading so I can attach listeners to elements?

Any help, much appreciated!

Comment: Does Civi have an event similar to Bootstrap? ala: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_modal_event_shown&stacked=h

Comment: A different solution to your aim is to use https://civicrm.org/extensions/profile-conditionals

Comment: Thanks @Aidan but it's not just conditional fields, but also hierarchical selects. So that extension would mean more customisation in PHP.

Comment: I've also tried this pattern to attach to Profile page loads. https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildProfile/ However this attaches on load, rather than when complete so back to the same issue.